Integral by parts on a scalar field over a curve
Let $M$ be a compact and boundaryless Riemannian manifold. Take $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and let $T_s(x)=\exp_x(s\nabla f(x))$ be its gradient flow.
I have proven for my specific case that
$$\int_0^1\Delta f(T_s(x))ds=0$$
with $\Delta$ being the Laplace operator.
Am I allowed to use a "integration by parts in this case"? I mean,
$$\int_0^1\Delta f(T_s(x))ds=\int_0^1\langle\nabla f(x),s\nabla f(x)\rangle ds,$$
or something similar?
I would be really glad if I could prove that $\nabla f\equiv 0$.

By integration by parts you mean Stokes’s Theorem on a compact manifold with boundary? This has nothing to do with integration by parts on $[0,1]$. Maybe you want to consider $\int_M\int_{[0,1]}$ and change the order of integration.

@TedShifrin, I've tryied this, but it led me to nowhere
